# Changing the order of elements and wrap after specific element with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create this structure using only flexbox.

[image]

This is how my html looks like.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first_container"></div>
  <div class="second_container"></div>
  <div class="third_container"></div>
</div>
```

I know it's really basic problem if i could just change divs order or add additional wrapper for the first line. The problem is it have to stay as it is.

Basic dimensions:
 1. first_container - should takes 100% minus third_container width
 2. second_container - shoudl takes 100%

I am asking for some tips, because my hands are slowly falling.

Comment: are u using bootstrap?

Comment: You want to look into `order`. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/.

Comment: @Shaik In this specific element I don't.

Comment: @AjAX I'm already trying, but i have problem how to wrap after specific element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flexbox order property

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

.first_container {
  width: 70%;
  order: 1;
}

.second_container {
  width: 100%;
  order: 3;
}

.third_container {
  width: 30%;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first_container">1</div>
  <div class="second_container">2</div>
  <div class="third_container">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I also remaked childs width to flex-basis and it's perfect solution. I will keep in mind.